# How to make static variable have the same initialization value in shared library and in main program, in a templated class method?

Tags: c++, templates, static, shared-libraries

I have created a TypeManager class that permit me to create an Id for a 
given class type. This is a simplest version of the method that make this possible :

```
template<typename T>
int64_t getTypeId() {
    static int64_t type = typeCounter++;
    return type;
}
```

This class is used by my main program and also multiples shared libraries. The problem is that method create differents Ids for each same class type, when there are in differents libraries.

How can I make this work without having differents Id for each shared libraries ? Do there is a solution without a static ? Maybe, I can make this work with a compilation flag ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Q: What platform?  Windows?  Linux?  Other?  Q: What compiler?  MSVS? GCC?  Other?

Comment: I'm on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.1). My compiler is Gcc. But I need to make this work also on Windows.

Comment: Actually if you have a solution only for Linux I'll take that ;).

Answer (score 0):

Create a shared library.  It maintains a map from mangled type name to index.

Call this `int64_t get_type_integer( std::type_index )`.  Export it, make it thread safe, etc.

Don't call it.

Instead call

```
template<typename T>
int64_t getTypeId() {
  static int64_t type = details::get_type_integer(typeid(T));
  return type;
}
```

now each so has a type it uses magic statics to access/init; get type integer only gets called once per .so per type.  So the code in there can be written safe rather than super fast.

Use names and not `type_index` directly because the same type in two so's on many systems can be considered different types but can have the same mangled type name.

Comment: I already come with a solution with a vector of mangled type name but it was'nt as efficient as the version I had with my static. But this can fix this problem. Thanks